# Adding and Subtracting numbers from a String

Tags: java, regex, string, delimiter

This program takes in a string and adds up all the integers in it, I have set the delimiter to be "+" surrounded by any amount of white space.
It works fine with that but now I want it to work with any negative integers as well, for instance if I input "8 + 33 + 1,345 - 37"; the output is 41.It doesn't even get to 1,345
or subtracts -37 from the total. Are delimiters "skipped" ? For instance, would I be correct if I say the compiler goes to 8 and then '+' is skipped then it goes to 33? And if I 
set the delimiter to be "\s*\+|-\s*" (an attempt of + or -), the output is still 41, why?

```
import java.util.*; 

import java.io.*;

public class Add_em_up
  {

            public static void main (String args [])            

        {     

            Scanner x = new Scanner (System.in);


            System.out.print("Enter something like 8 + 33 + 1,345 + 137 :");


            String s = x.nextLine();

            Scanner sc1 = new Scanner (s);
            sc1.useDelimiter("\\s*\\+\\s*");                

            int sum = 0;
            while (sc1.hasNextInt())
            {
                sc1.skip(",*");
                if (sc1.hasNextInt())
                {
                    sum = sum + sc1.nextInt();                 
                }

            }
            System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum);
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put `+`, `-` inside a character class.

```
sc1.useDelimiter("\\s*[-+]\\s*");
```

Comment: `sc1.split("\\s*[-+]\\s*"); `

Comment: It works thanks, but why do we have to remove "\\" and why doesn't it work with +|- doesn't "|" mean or as well?

Comment: `|` not applies to the plus and minus. It takes the whole part on the left and whole part on the right.

Comment: And do you say that the delimiters are "skipped" when compiling? Is "skip" the correct terminology? How do YOU think about delimiters?

Answer (score 1):

Okay here's an easy solution if you are interested in using the library [Exp4j](http://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/). Library will do all the calculation and all you've to do is pass the equation and get the result.

Here's an example.

```
Expression e = new ExpressionBuilder("3 * sin(y) - 2 / (x - 2)")
    .variables("x", "y")
    .build()
    .setVariable("x", 2.3)
    .setVariable("y", 3.14);
double result = e.evaluate();
```